# Backbone.js - Insert new view item in order

Tags: javascript, view, backbone.js

I am using very similar code to the Backbone ToDo example - http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html.

After I insert a new model into the collection, I sort the collection.  The todo example appends the new data to the end of the view

```
  var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
  $("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
```

I want to insert my model data into the view according to its position within the collection and not merely to last place.  Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First get the index of the newly added model in the collection (after the sort ). You can get it with the underscore method `indexOf` i.e. `index = todoColl.indexOf(todo);`.

Then use the  :eq() jQuery selector to get the item currently at this position in the list, and .before() your new item, i.e. `$("li:eq(" + index.toString() + ")").before(view.render().el);` (assuming the view renders a li element). Careful, add code to manage the case if the new item is last (in which case the jQuery selector will be empty).

Comment: thanks, mine was a table so I only had to change `li` to `tr` and it works perfectly.  thanks again.